# Pyinstaller does not create an .exe file in dist folder

Tags: python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

I installed Pyinstaller successfully. I followed the steps as given here: **Using PyInstaller**. When I type `pyinstaller myscript.py` in command window, it creates myscript.spec, the build folder (including myscript.exe.manifest) and the dist folder. However, the dist folder is created as empty. Hence, no myscript.exe file can be found there.

I am using PyInstaller-3.0 and Python2.7(64-bit).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using PyInstaller: [link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem is related to hook-six-moves.py. It should be exactly as same as [hook-six.moves.py](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/1393/files).